# Func<IQueryable<InputObj> delegate issue in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, delegates

When I try to call to my function, it's returning this error

> Error CS0411
> The type arguments for method 'QueryExtensions.GetODataQueryResultAsync(IQueryable, ODataQueryOptions, bool, ODataValidationSettings?, IAsyncQueryExecutor?)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Error occurs in this code:

```
return this._service
   .GetAllDataView<ViewObj>(this.UserContext, quaryable => quaryable.GetODataQueryResultAsync(queryOptions)).OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

`GetODataQueryResultAsync` is an extension method:

This is the `GetAllDataView` function inside code:

```
public List<ViewObj> GetAllDataView <T>(UserContext userContext, Func<IQueryable<Engagement>, Task<T>> odataExecute)
{
    using var dbContextSetup = this._dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

    IRepository _repository = new Repository(dbContextSetup, userContext);

    return this._serviceHelper.MapToEngagementsView((IQueryable<Engagement>)odataExecute(_repository .GetAllReadOnly())).ToList();
}
```